# LXC run command on containers

Tags: lxc

Is there a way to run a command for example fdisk -l on all the running LXC containers from the host?

```
lxc-execute requires --name option
```

Answer (score 3):

The following command will output the name (and only the name) of each running container, one per line:

```
lxc ls volatile.last_state.power=RUNNING -c n --format csv
```

We can use it in a bash for loop as follows:

```
for container in `lxc ls volatile.last_state.power=RUNNING -c n --format csv`; do lxc exec $container <command>; done
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Please update your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a few lines of bash, no need to install PHP on the host.

**LXC1.0**

```
#!/bin/bash

for container in $(lxc-ls -1 --running); do
    lxc-attach -n "$container" -- /bin/bash -c "fdisk -l"
done
```

**LXD/LXC2.0+**

```
#!/bin/bash

for container in $(lxc list volatile.last_state.power=RUNNING -c n --format csv); do    
    lxc exec "$container" "fdisk -l"
done
```

**LXD/LXC3.0+** (added by [@l422y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887164/l422y) 12/2020)

```
#!/bin/bash

for container in $(lxc list volatile.last_state.power=RUNNING -c n --format csv); do    
    lxc exec "$container" -- fdisk -l
done
```

Comment: @LarryWilliamson thanks for edit, glad it helped, dont people upvote helpful answers now days 4k views.. tempted to delete

Answer (score 0):

```
from pylxd import Client
import os
conn=Client()

def ExecuteCommandOn(command):
    for i in conn.containers.all():
        if i.status.upper()=="RUNNING":
           query = "lxc exec %s -- %s" % (i.name,command)
            os.system(query)

def main():
    ExecuteCommandOn("uptime")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have an php interpreter on host node, you can use this snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php


if(!@is_executable('/usr/bin/lxc-attach'))
{
    print "This host is probably not an LXC host.\n";
    exit;




$ret=@exec('/usr/bin/lxc-ls');
$vzs=explode(' ',$ret);

exec('clear');

print "Executing \"".$argv[1]."\" command on all containers...\n";
sleep(1);

foreach($vzs as $k)
{
    print "Executing \"".$argv[1]."\" command on $k...\n";
    passthru('/usr/bin/lxc-attach -n '.$k.' -- '.$argv[1]);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Code-Only answers are not considered as good answers. Please improve your answer by providing more context and explanations.